Maximal planar graph with $n$ vertices
Suppose $n$ is a natural number. Suppose that $0 \leq m(n) \leq n^2$ is the maximum natural number such that there exists a planar graph with $n$ vertices and $m(n)$ edges.
Is it true that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{m(n)}{n^2} \rightarrow 0$?

Thanks! That answers the question. However, is there another proof for the claim  from first principles?

Yes. More specifically, $m(n)=3n-6$ exactly for all $n\ge 3$.
A planar graph which you cannot add any edges to without making it nonplanar is called maximal planar. Necessarily, all faces of a maximal planar graph are triangles. Letting $F$ be the number of faces, and $E$ be the number of edges, the fact that all faces are triangles implies $3F=2E$. This equation, combined with Euler's formula, $V-E+F=2$, implies that $E=3V-6$.
See the wikipedia article on maximal planar graphs.
